# getElementById vs $('#element') to get input field length

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the input field:

```
<input type="text" id="papaya">
```

Why does this work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert($('#papaya').val().length);
});
```

but this does not?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pp = document.getElementById('papaya');
    alert(pp.val().length);
});
```

Comment: `val()` is a function that is only provided by jQuery objects, not by pure DOM elements.

Comment: `pp.value` or `$(pp).val()`

Comment: use `pp.value.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in your first example, `pp` is a reference to a jQuery object, which is a wrapper around a set of elements that provides the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com), but in your second example, it's a direct reference to the DOM element, which doesn't have jQuery methods like `val`, but does have its own methods and properties, including `.value`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pp = document.getElementById('papaya');
    alert(pp.value.length);
    // -----^^^^^^^
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use value for javascript:

```
alert(pp.value.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla js you need to use `value` instead of `val()`. The `val()` function is a jQuery own implementation.

```js
var pp = document.getElementById('papaya');
console.log(pp.value.length);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="papaya" value="123">
```